# How to update/refresh changed partlabels as reported by lsblk?

Tags: linux, udev, partition-table, sysfs, lsblk

On Linux, the command `lsblk -o partlabel` will display the `partlabel` for block devices.

I have used `gdisk` to change a `partlabel`.

After the change, `lsblk` is still reporting the old value of the `partlabel`.

(Aside: The paths `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/*` are also still using the old `partlabel` values.)

Is there some way to refresh the cache so that `lsblk` will report the new value of the `partlabel`?

I'm not sure exactly where the cache is.  It may be udev, sysfs, or somewhere else.

By contrast, `blkid` correctly reports the new `partlabel`.  However, I'm hoping I can avoid switching to `blkid` (for various reasons).

(Aside: A reboot will probably update the `partlabel` values.  But I'd prefer to avoid rebooting, if possible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer: `sudo udevadm trigger`

Source: http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-refresh-devdisk-on-linux.html

Update #1:  It appears the `sudo` may be unnecessary.  So: `udevadm trigger`

Update #2:  It appears that `sudo` is necessary to propagate a changed Btrfs filesystem label.  (While this is not the question I originally asked, I figure it is worth mentioning here.)  So, if `udevadm trigger` changes nothing, then it may worth trying `sudo udevadm trigger`.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would guess the command `partprobe` would also do the job, perhaps with a bit more focused fashion than `udevadm trigger`.

Comment: `partprobe` did not work for me.  I had tried it.  I suspect it would detect new/removed partitions, or changes in partition size.

Comment: Huh. Well, good to know!